# Yup with Formik, LessThan or Equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm-scripts, formik, yup

I'm using something like this:

```
schema.number
        .lessThan(
          value,
          `You own only ${value}.`)
```

It works great. If, however, if value = 60, all numbers up to 60 work, but without 60. I can't do: value + 1. Is there any method like: lessThanOrEqualto()?
I need (∞; 60>
I have (∞; 60)

https://github.com/jquense/yup

Comment: After looking at Yup docs, there's no lessThanOrEqual function, maybe try working with the value +1 solution.

Comment: I do not work only on integers.

Comment: @konradowski, what else do u work on besides integers?

Answer (score 6):

You can use ***max*** instead of ***lessThan*** or in you case:

```
schema
  .number
  .max(value,`You own only ${value}.`)
```

If you think about the logic ***max*** means highest possible or with other words ***less than or equal***

Comment: Yup (Less than or equal to)

https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/538#issuecomment-495340254

Comment: number().max(5) is <= 5

Answer (score 0):

you can use .test as

```
.test('test less than', `You own only ${CONSTANT}`, value =>
  value <= CONSTANT
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for a close equivalent of "less than or equal to" 100:

```
yup.number().required("An amount is required").lessThan(
        100.000000001,
        `Amount must be less than 100%`)
});
```

Add or remove decimals to change the precision. As this is now, 100.0001 will fail, as will 100 and anything more than 100.000000001.